Opengraph doesn't show
So I want my website to have an opengraph preview. For that I coded a new system in my index.html file which goes like this:
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#navbar").load("navbar.html");
  $("#header").load("header.html");
});

And then the navbar loads here in a div:
<div id="navbar"></div>

The navbar works fine, but the header is having some issues.
I put the header here before the <head> ends:
<div id="header"></div>

I tried doing this as the code for the header:
<!-- HTML Meta Tags -->
<title>M100</title>
<meta name="description" content="Thing">

<!-- Facebook Meta Tags -->
<meta property="og:url" content="https://micamaster100.github.io/">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="M100">
<meta property="og:description" content="Thing">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://opengraph.b-cdn.net/production/images/6956cfb8-f271-4cc5-bea6-965c7ce33b70.png?token=UTylE3SBRlkQmuQGqlHtvBVjJSbd8Wh6iZV5TvXLWF0&height=675&width=1200&expires=33258560618">

<!-- Twitter Meta Tags -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="twitter:domain" content="micamaster100.github.io">
<meta property="twitter:url" content="https://micamaster100.github.io/">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="M100">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Thing">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://opengraph.b-cdn.net/production/images/6956cfb8-f271-4cc5-bea6-965c7ce33b70.png?token=UTylE3SBRlkQmuQGqlHtvBVjJSbd8Wh6iZV5TvXLWF0&height=675&width=1200&expires=33258560618">

<!-- Meta Tags Generated via https://www.opengraph.xyz -->

And only get the title but not the social media preview.
edit: looking at the website now does have the social media preview, but I added the opengraph directly into the index.html. My goal here is to have that in a seperate script.

<div> elements cannot go inside <head>

Open Graph parsers typically do not execute JavaScript and thus will never see tags you're loading via AJAX requests or generating client-side.

How do I change my script to allow that while keeping the header code in a seperate file?

OP says the title works though

@Phil The tab gets a title in-browser (because the browser does execute the JS), but https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fmicamaster100.github.io%2F and https://www.opengraph.xyz/url/https%3A%2F%2Fmicamaster100.github.io%2F don't see a title.

@ceejayoz oh, that screenshot is a browser tab, gotcha.
